# Registration Form check PostgreSQL is username is already taken

Tags: php, validation, postgresql, forms

Hey I'm really new to PHP and PostgreSQP or any database in that matter. So I'm at a loss how to do this.

I need an if statement that says.

```
If(the username user just typed in is already in database) {
  my code here
}
```

the variable the username that the user just typed in is $userNameSignup

how would I do that with PHP for PostgreSQL?

also how might I redirect people to a new page once they have completed the form properly?

Thanks
Shelby

Comment: I don't want to be a drag, but are you really planning on building a logon/user registration (read: security) system with *no knowledge* of the tools you use whatsoever? Maybe starting with something simpler would be a good idea. Just sayin'.

Comment: actually my form is 95% complete with no errors aside from what I asked for. I want to learn real life application for PHP so I'm going to jump to what I'm actually going to use it for. Logins... I don't care if my brain explodes I take 10 years to figure it out. I need to know and need to learn. but the faster the better and so far this is the fastest way I personally learn

Comment: as well as I am not new to programming I'm just new to server-side programming.

Comment: What is so special about "server side programming"? What I mean is this: Evidently you have no idea where to start. Try to get some basic stuff working first (for example: how to get values out of a database), and if you are that far, post some code that you have come up with. People might be able to help you better with a concrete question than with a broad request along the lines of "write code for me that does such and such".

Comment: -_- I can't get info out of a database without info in a database -_- so I have to make a form to insert the information. So far I have.

  $result = pg_query('SELECT 1 FROM logins WHERE LOWER(userName)=\''.strtolower(pg_escape_string('.$userNameSignup.')).'\'');

  if (!pg_num_rows($result)) {
   
   $userNameSignupError = "Username already exists please choose a new one";
   $error = true;
   
  }

but its not working. Please don't discourage the way I learn and what I need to accomplish.

Comment: I'm not discouraging the way you learn, only the way you've asked this question. You've even figured something out on your own already, and that's what you should have done right away. P.S.: You can edit your own posts, its easier than posting code to the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $result = pg_query('SELECT 1 FROM logins WHERE LOWER(userName)=\''.strtolower(pg_escape_string($userNameSignup)).'\'') or exit(pg_last_error());

    if (pg_num_rows($result)) {

        $userNameSignupError = 'Username already taken please choose a new one.';
    }
```

finally figured it out ^.^

Comment: You are much better off using $result = pg_query_params('SELECT 1 FROM logins WHERE lower(username)=$1', array($userNameSignup))      It'll be both faster and less subject to small mistakes causing security problems.